# JQuery booklet add search bar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

now i have installed Moleskine jquery booklet plugin, and i have made changes to view the data in the pages by fetching from DB (mysql), i have added a form so whenever i submit this form it creates a new page in the booklet.

the thing here is i need to add search bar to direct user to a certain page as pages are getting too many.

i tried the below basic div search but its not working, any help with that would be appreciated.

the booklet div html as follows :

```
<input id="pagesearch" type="text" placeholder="Learn Something ...">

    <div class="book_wrapper" id="sbooksch">
        <a id="next_page_button"></a>
        <a id="prev_page_button"></a>
        <div id="loading" class="loading">Loading pages...</div>
        <div id="mybook" style="display:none;">
            <div class="b-load">
            
            
                            <?php include 'php/booklet.php';?>
                
            
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*div search javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#pagesearch").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
$("#sbooksch*").filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
 });
 });
 </script>
```

- booklet.php :

  ````
  if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
  { 
     session_start(); 
  } 

  $servername = "localhost";
  $username   = "root";
  $password   = "";
  $dbname     = "booklet";
  $user_id    = $_SESSION["user_id"];


  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  $sql  = "SELECT *   FROM `booklet` order by log_id;";



  if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
  do {
  $result = mysqli_store_result($conn);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1 ) {
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     $_SESSION['log_id'] = $row['log_id'];   
  echo '<div>' ;



  $log_id  = $row['log_id'];

  echo ' <a  id="'.$row['log_id'].'" title="'.$row['subject'].'" href="'. 
  $row['link'] .'" target="_blank">
     <img src="images/logbook_temp.png" /> 
         </a>   '


  ?>  


  <?php
  echo'<h1> '.$row['subject'].'  </h1>';

  ?>
  <p style="color:#3c597e;">text :</p><p><?php echo nl2br($row['text']) ;?> 
  </p>
  <?php
  if( isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['admin'] == 'X' ){
  echo"           <a href='php/delete_log.php?log_id={$row['log_id']}' 
  style='bottom:7%; position:absolute;' onclick=\"return confirm('Are You 
  Sure You want to delete this Log?')\" class='text'>Delete</a>";
  }
  echo "</div>";
  }

  } 
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  } while (mysqli_more_results($conn));
  }

  ?>    ```
  ````
- calling the booklet Javascript :

  ````
    $(function() {
      var $mybook     = $('#mybook');
      var $bttn_next    = $('#next_page_button');
      var $bttn_prev    = $('#prev_page_button');
      var $loading    = $('#loading');
      var $mybook_images  = $mybook.find('img');
      var cnt_images    = $mybook_images.length;
      var loaded      = 0;
      //preload all the images in the book,
      //and then call the booklet plugin

      $mybook_images.each(function(){
        var $img  = $(this);
        var source  = $img.attr('src');
        $('<img/>').load(function(){
          ++loaded;
          if(loaded == cnt_images){
            $loading.hide();
            $bttn_next.show();
            $bttn_prev.show();
            $mybook.show().booklet({
              name:               null,                            // name of the booklet to display in 
   the document title bar
              width:              800,                             // container width
              height:             500,                             // container height
              speed:              600,                             // speed of the transition between 
  pages
              direction:          'LTR',                           // direction of the overall content 
  organization, default LTR, left to right, can be RTL for languages which read right to left
              startingPage:       0,                               // index of the first page to be 
  displayed
              easing:             'easeInOutQuad',                 // easing method for complete 
  transition
              easeIn:             'easeInQuad',                    // easing method for first half of 
  transition
              easeOut:            'easeOutQuad',                   // easing method for second half of 
  transition

              closed:             true,                           // start with the book "closed", will 
  add empty pages to beginning and end of book
              closedFrontTitle:   null,                            // used with "closed", "menu" and 
  "pageSelector", determines title of blank starting page
              closedFrontChapter: null,                            // used with "closed", "menu" and 
  "chapterSelector", determines chapter name of blank starting page
              closedBackTitle:    null,                            // used with "closed", "menu" and 
  "pageSelector", determines chapter name of blank ending page
              closedBackChapter:  null,                            // used with "closed", "menu" and 
  "chapterSelector", determines chapter name of blank ending page
              covers:             false,                           // used with  "closed", makes first 
  and last pages into covers, without page numbers (if enabled)

              pagePadding:        10,                              // padding for each page wrapper
              pageNumbers:        true,                            // display page numbers on each page

              hovers:             false,                            // enables preview pageturn hover 
  animation, shows a small preview of previous or next page on hover
              overlays:           false,                            // enables navigation using a page 
  sized overlay, when enabled links inside the content will not be clickable
              tabs:               false,                           // adds tabs along the top of the 
  pages
              tabWidth:           60,                              // set the width of the tabs
              tabHeight:          20,                              // set the height of the tabs
              arrows:             false,                           // adds arrows overlayed over the 
   book edges
              cursor:             'pointer',                       // cursor css setting for side bar 
  areas

              hash:               false,                           // enables navigation using a hash 
  string, ex: #/page/1 for page 1, will affect all booklets with 'hash' enabled
              keyboard:           true,                            // enables navigation with arrow 
  keys (left: previous, right: next)
              next:               $bttn_next,               // selector for element to use as click 
  trigger for next page
              prev:               $bttn_prev,               // selector for element to use as click 
  trigger for previous page

              menu:               null,                            // selector for element to use as 
   the menu area, required for 'pageSelector'
              pageSelector:       false,                           // enables navigation with a 
  dropdown menu of pages, requires 'menu'
              chapterSelector:    false,                           // enables navigation with a 
  dropdown menu of chapters, determined by the "rel" attribute, requires 'menu'

              shadows:            true,                            // display shadows on page 
  animations
              shadowTopFwdWidth:  166,                             // shadow width for top forward anim
              shadowTopBackWidth: 166,                             // shadow width for top back anim
              shadowBtmWidth:     50,                              // shadow width for bottom shadow

              before:             function(){},                    // callback invoked before each page 
  turn animation
              after:              function(){}                     // callback invoked after each page 
  turn animation
            });
            Cufon.refresh();
          }
        }).attr('src',source);
      });

    });
      </script> ```
  ````

- EDIT :

i realized that i placed the id="sbooksch" in wrong div, it should be in the page loading div as below:

but it only returns the text not the whole div .. any suggestion.

```
        <div class="book_wrapper" >
        <a id="next_page_button"></a>
        <a id="prev_page_button"></a>
        <div id="loading" class="loading">Loading pages...</div>
        <div id="mybook" style="display:none;">
            <div class="b-load" id="sbooksch">
            
            
                            <?php include 'php/booklet.php';?>
                
            
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i edit the question

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help you **debug your code**. Take a quick look at a [coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit.